# Issue with TextInput element in the bottom of a FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, textinput

TextInputs at the bottom of the screen in a FlatList automatically and immediately dismiss the keyboard on focus, making it impossible to write anything in it.
The issue is reproducible easily on a blank react-native init project. I tested it in Nexus 5x simulator and real device. I reproduce the bug every time on 0.61.

Related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13745

Answer (score 1):

Just add one props in your `FlatList` as below:

```
<FlatList
     keyboardDismissMode={'none'}
     .....
</FlatList>
```

Chears.!

Comment: This does not solve for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't give the component reference to the `Flatlist` footer because when we update state of the component then arrow function creates a new reference that's why `TextInput` loses it's focus. Just return direct View to the `Flatlist` footer.

```
<FlatList
  data={...}
  ListFooterComponent={renderYourFooter()}
/>
```

or

```
<FlatList
  data={...}
  ListFooterComponent={<View>
    <TextInput/>
  </View>}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved for me. I was doing `ListFooterComponent={renderSuggestionInput}` instead of `ListFooterComponent={renderSuggestionInput()}`

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was two folds. First off I was doing the mistake of passing the function instead of passing the element. So, I followed @br jangid answer and just called my function. So this:

```
ListFooterComponent={renderSuggestionInput}
```

got changed to this:

```
ListFooterComponent={renderSuggestionInput()}
```

The above fix solved the problem on my Android device, but it was still breaking on other Android device, so I had to add `removeClippedSubviews={false}` to my `FlatList`, which then solved the problem on the other devices too.

This is the complete code for my `FlatList`:

```
            <FlatList
                ListHeaderComponent={renderInstructions()}
                ListHeaderComponentStyle={styles.instructionContainer}
                data={features}
                renderItem={renderFeature}
                keyExtractor={(feature) => feature.id.toString()}
                ListFooterComponent={renderSuggestionInput()}
                ListFooterComponentStyle={styles.suggestionContainer}
                removeClippedSubviews={false}
            />
```